# Android HttpURLConnection, load only first 4066 symbol, and breaks request

Tags: java, android

The problem is that I do not get a full result. And only some part, that is not part of the sales, and the first 4066 characters.The problem is the same, IOException not seem to be caused by

```
private class GetContent extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String resultJson = "";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bSFiRdwiSq?indent=2");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            resultJson = buffer.toString();

            Log.d("Result:", resultJson);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}`
```

Result

`D/RESULT:: [  {    "guid": "fdaefcc1-6469-4e3a-9d03-722f8de768d9",     "index": 0,     "favoriteFruit": "banana",     "latitude": 52.644930000000002,     "company": "DECRATEX",     "email": "jodiecollier@decratex.com",     "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",     "tags": [      "esse",       "tempor",       "fugiat",       "labore",       "eu",       "aliquip",       "fugiat"    ],     "registered": "2015-06-07T09:21:48 -06:00",     "eyeColor": "blue",     "phone": "+1 (870) 541-3015",     "address": "503 Rugby Road, Defiance, Alaska, 2923",     "friends": [      {        "id": 0,         "name": "Melton Reese"      },       {        "id": 1,         "name": "Sara Gilbert"      },       {        "id": 2,         "name": "Nicholson Weber"      }    ],     "isActive": false,     "about": "Fugiat Lorem mollit in pariatur incididunt est cupidatat veniam sit officia. Dolor dolor velit ex fugiat dolore officia enim quis in pariatur do ea. Ipsum cillum duis aliquip ut occaecat qui sint est aliqua consequat reprehenderit non. Velit pariatur aute voluptate minim in deserunt amet duis laborum laborum amet. Fugiat nostrud culpa ipsum Lorem proident pariatur aliqua fugiat culpa. Et aliquip magna exercitation ipsum aute voluptate. Dolore magna sint duis ipsum eu consectetur.\r\n",     "balance": "$3,384.03",     "name": "Jodie Collier",     "gender": "female",     "age": 27,     "greeting": "Hello, Jodie Collier! You have 3 unread messages.",     "longitude": 173.90763799999999,     "_id": "58046a786230071a551569b9"  },   {    "guid": "badaf4d6-54fa-46e3-8a6d-6b6997483b00",     "index": 1,     "favoriteFruit": "strawberry",     "latitude": 39.709885,     "company": "DRAGBOT",     "email": "alstonmays@dragbot.com",     "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",     "tags": [      "elit",       "ea",       "ipsum",       "velit",       "amet",       "laborum",       "duis"    ],     "registered": "2016-06-01T05:06:26 -06:00",     "eyeColor": "green",     "phone": "+1 (911) 423-3011",     "address": "248 Forbell Street, Mathews, Vermont, 4994",     "friends": [      {        "id": 0,         "name": "Liza Day"      },       {        "id": 1,         "name": "Catherine Palmer"      },       {        "id": 2,         "name": "Beryl Conway"      }    ],     "isActive": false,     "about": "Proident id fugiat pariatur et incididunt commodo est irure in duis ullamco veniam est magna. Id enim qui commodo exercitation labore adipisicing excepteur adipisicing dolor veniam. Qui quis minim commodo mollit est sit.\r\n",     "balance": "$1,375.60",     "name": "Alston Mays",     "gender": "male",     "age": 33,     "greeting": "Hello, Alston Mays! You have 10 unread messages.",     "longitude": -67.445130000000006,     "_id": "58046a78a50c13da27ab0d11"  },   {    "guid": "e328c11c-f948-42a6-aede-179ec44a7873",     "index": 2,     "favoriteFruit": "apple",     "latitude": 17.807843999999999,     "company": "INSOURCE",     "email": "cassandramcintyre@insource.com",     "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",     "tags": [      "et",       "anim",       "dolor",       "magna",       "quis",       "occaecat",       "dolor"    ],     "registered": "2015-09-11T03:36:24 -06:00",     "eyeColor": "blue",     "phone": "+1 (865) 558-2301",     "address": "189 Cranberry Street, Riverton, Arkansas, 5369",     "friends": [      {        "id": 0,         "name": "Whitley Howe"      },       {        "id": 1,         "name": "Roseann Perez"      },       {        "id": 2,         "name": "Sasha Richard"      }    ],     "isActive": false,     "about": "Consequat adipisicing ut dolor in. Id enim consectetur qui incididunt non amet laboris. Veniam amet dolore proident est proident dolor sunt nulla est quis veniam commodo anim. Ut exercitation excepteur enim quis et ea veniam non laboris duis. Dolore cillum commodo dolore reprehenderit aliqua labore.\r\n",     "balance": "$3,678.92",     "name": "Cassandra Mcintyre",     "gender": "female",     "age": 29,     "greeting": "Hello, Cassandra Mcintyre! You have 8 unread messages.",     "longitude": 93.`

Comment: Have you tried just output only length of response?

Comment: What is the meaning of '`IOException` not seem to be caused by'?

Comment: Your data is only being truncated by the message log.  I'll bet that if you go into the debugger and examine `buffer`, your entire JSON string will be there.

Comment: @kris unfortunately no data is actually cut off. Then I transfer data from listview where I see only 1-2 items

Comment: my mistake, not correctly process the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few points that you need to implement in your code.

1. urlConnection.connect(); is not important when we call  urlConnection.getInputStream(); then it automatically call the Url.
2. Close every Stream that you Open.

So the code will be

```
private class GetContent extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;
String resultJson = "";

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try{
        URL url = new URL("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bSFiRdwiSq?indent=2");

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int line;
        while ((line=reader.read()) > 0){
            builder.append((char)line);
        }
        reader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        String resultJson = builder.toString();

        Log.d("Result:", resultJson);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Now it was so, loading up `"name": "Cassandra Mcintyre",`

Comment: All true but doesn't change anything that would solve the problem. `line` is a strange name for a variable that doesn't hold a line.

Answer (score 0):

Your read logic should be something like this:

```
InputStream in = mConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, enconding));    
int ch;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();         

while ((ch=reader.read()) > 0) {            
    sb.append((char)ch);
}

String resultjson= sb.toString().trim();
Log.d("Result:", resultJson);
```

Comment: than's for the tip, but it did not change anything. All the same.

Comment: it does, instead of reading line read character by character.

Comment: Now it was so, loading up `"name": "Cassandra Mcintyre",`

Comment: Please explain why you think your suggestion is superior to the OP's code.